# Ubuntu 12.04 -- php-config5 points to 5.3 instead 5.4

Tags: 12.04, php

I have a problem installing a php extension (Phalcon framework) due to having upgraded from php 5.3 to 5.4 some time ago.

I upgraded using ondrej-php5-precise repository. Everything is working ok and if I run phpinfo I get that the version is

from cli:

```
PHP 5.4.17-1~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jul 17 2013 18:14:06)
```

from web:

```
PHP Version 5.4.17-1~precise+1
```

But if I run `php-config5 --version` I get
`5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11`

And now when I try to install phalcon it compiles it for php5.3 instead of php5.4.

I've read on the forums that I need to use the right phpize for 5.4 when building it. But I have two files phpize and phpize5 (same for php-config and php-config5) and both point to php5.3 version

Stev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you haven't upgraded php5-dev package - try searching for a package: dpkg -S $(which php-config5) and upgrade the package using ppa to match the php version.

The other most probable cause is some local forgotten installation of php5.3 - look in /usr/local

Comment: I've upgraded php5-dev package and that brought everything to php5.5.12 and the installation of phalcon went smoothly.